# how to get value from the editText in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to get value from EditText in a listView .How to get value from EditText in a listView??I'm new in android programming, someone can help me?

i have a structure like this in my ListView

TextView EditText EditText

TextView EditText EditText

TextView EditText EditText

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
private myAdapter adapter;
private List<member>member_list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    set_list();
}
private void set_list()
{
    member_list = new ArrayList<>();
    member_list.add(new member("ABC","1","1"));
    member_list.add(new member("ABC","2","1"));
    member_list.add(new member("ABC","1","2"));
    member_list.add(new member("ABC","0","0"));
    member_list.add(new member("ABC","2","2"));
    member_list.add(new member("ABC","1","0"));
    adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext(),member_list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

myAdapter

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<member>member_list ;
private Context context;
public myAdapter(Context context,List<member> member_list)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.member_list = member_list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return member_list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return member_list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = View.inflate(context,R.layout.textview,null);
    TextView t_name;
    EditText t_text1,t_text2;
    t_name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.t_name);
    t_text1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.t_text1);
    t_text2 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.t_text2);
    t_name.setText(member_list.get(position).getName());
    t_text1.setText(member_list.get(position).getNum1());
    t_text2.setText(member_list.get(position).getNum2());
    v.setTag(member_list.get(position));
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("OpenDbListAdapter ","List View Clicked");
        String txt2 = t_text1.getText().toString();
        Log.i("t_text1", "" + txt2);
    }
});
```

Add this in your adapter and make sure you defined Textview and Edittext values global. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text from **EditText** when click. You should add listener to your **EditText** and let your **EditText** accepts the click event but not you **List**. 
At first:

- `android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true"` You can find similar set function in code insight
- set `onClickListener` to your EditText and call `edittext.getText().toString()` is ok

Hope this will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

To access the EditText values in your MainActivity, update your getView method like this:

```
@Override
//Make sure you set position as final here
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ....
    EditText t_text1,t_text2;
   .....

    t_text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
             ((MainActivity)context).textChanged(position, charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    return v;
}
.....
```

Then in MainActivity create a method `textChanged()`

In general it's not great practice to cast `context` as a specific activity as it makes it more difficult to reuse this adapter elsewhere, but it should work for your purposes.